# Datagridview show date or time (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview in which some columns where initially specified as String and they contain date or time, depending on some bussiness logic.

I am changing the type of the column (to datetime) to allow correct sorting. And I would like to know if it is possible to show date values or time values depending on the row. Or I will always have to show both.

Thank you.

Comment: depending on row or column?

Comment: @tezzo row, depending on the column would be much easier

Comment: I asked to be sure because you talk about correct sorting of this column... and then mix date-only values with time-only values. but I don't know your business logic: maybe you display time-only value if day is today or something like this! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the `CellFormatting` event. This event is fired everytime a cell is painted. You can change what value is being displayed without changing the underlying value and the format of the cell.

By doing this you can change the format depending on the row and column

```
Private Sub CellFormatting_EventHandler(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs)
     If e.ColumnIndex = 2 AndAlso CType(sender, DataGridView)(5, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString = "Steve" Then 'Or whatever logic you like
         e.Value = CType(e.Value, Date).ToShortTimeString
     End If
 End Sub
```